# FELM + Stargazer - Align instrumental variables estimates with OLS

Tags: r, regression, stargazer

I have an felm object in R that I'm trying to make a table comparing the coefficient estimates from OLS estimation and IV estimation. The code below produces a table with two coefficient estimates, x and `x(fit)` in separate rows.

```
library(lfe)
library(stargazer)
n<-1000

u1<-rnorm(n)
u2<-rnorm(n)
z=3+0.5*rnorm(n)

x=0.5*z+u1
y=2*x+u2

df<-data.frame(y=y,x=x,z=z)

model1<-felm(y~x,data=df)
model2<-felm(y~1|0|(x~z),data=df)

stargazer(model1, model2, df)

===========================================================
                                   Dependent variable:     
                               ----------------------------
                                            y              
                                    (1)            (2)     
-----------------------------------------------------------
x                                 2.003***                 
                                  (0.031)                  

`x(fit)`                                        1.795***   
                                                 (0.149)   

Constant                           -0.041         0.274    
                                  (0.057)        (0.227)   

-----------------------------------------------------------
Observations                       1,000          1,000    
R2                                 0.804          0.796    
Adjusted R2                        0.804          0.795    
Residual Std. Error (df = 998)     1.005          1.027    
===========================================================
Note:                           *p<0.1; **p<0.05; ***p<0.01
```

What I'd like to have is a table like the following:

```
===========================================================
                                   Dependent variable:     
                               ----------------------------
                                            y              
                                    (1)            (2)     
-----------------------------------------------------------
x                                 2.003***        1.795***         
                                  (0.031)        (0.149)                                            

Constant                           -0.041         0.274    
                                  (0.057)        (0.227)   

-----------------------------------------------------------
Observations                       1,000          1,000    
R2                                 0.804          0.796    
Adjusted R2                        0.804          0.795    
Residual Std. Error (df = 998)     1.005          1.027    
===========================================================
Note:                           *p<0.1; **p<0.05; ***p<0.01
```

I tried doing

```
rownames(model2$coefficients)[rownames(model2$coefficients=="`x(fit)`"]<-"x"
```

but ran into an error in the Wald test. This is also annoying to do if I have multiple variables for which I'm instrumenting.

Is there a simpler way to align the covariates from different rows in Stargazer or R more broadly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use texreg instead of stargazer this is fairly straightforward:

```r
library(lfe)
library(texreg)

n<-1000

u1<-rnorm(n)
u2<-rnorm(n)
z=3+0.5*rnorm(n)

x=0.5*z+u1
y=2*x+u2

df<-data.frame(y=y,x=x,z=z)

model1<-felm(y~x,data=df)
model2<-felm(y~1|0|(x~z),data=df)

screenreg(list(model1, model2), 
          custom.coef.names = c("(Intercept)", "x", "x"))
#> 
#> ===============================================
#>                        Model 1      Model 2    
#> -----------------------------------------------
#> (Intercept)               0.05         0.11    
#>                          (0.05)       (0.13)   
#> x                         1.98 ***     1.93 ***
#>                          (0.03)       (0.09)   
#> -----------------------------------------------
#> Num. obs.              1000         1000       
#> R^2 (full model)          0.82         0.81    
#> R^2 (proj model)          0.82         0.81    
#> Adj. R^2 (full model)     0.81         0.81    
#> Adj. R^2 (proj model)     0.81         0.81    
#> ===============================================
#> *** p < 0.001, ** p < 0.01, * p < 0.05
```

As you can see this works by specifying a vector of coefficient labels, and if texreg finds these values duplicated it will place those estimates on the same row (incidentally to generate latex use `texreg(list(model1, model2))` instead of `screenreg`).

Also worth noting that if you insert an `NA` into `custom.coef.names` it will default back to the current name, so if you have 100 other covariates in the model, you could do `custom.coef.names = c(NA, "x", "x", rep(NA, 100))` instead of writing them all out.